# Sent WhatsApp Images do not appear in gallery

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, images, gallery

For uploading Instagram posts, the images need to be on my phone, so I tried sending the image on WhatsApp Desktop so that I have it on my phone, but this doesn't save it in the gallery. What can I do to automatically store these images and videos in my gallery?

If this is not possible, is there an app or something that automatically sends a WhatsApp message back to me, so I can send my images to that number and it sends it to me so they appear in my gallery?

Comment: @beeshyams I already tried all of those, this is what I normally do,  I also removed all the .nomedia files and I activated media visibility and I checked my secure folder.

Comment: @beeshyams nothing works, all of the online tutorials don't work. I even have a new mobile phone and new phone number, nothing works

Comment: Can you check your WhatsApp directory and see if they are saved on some other folder, for instance documents? (`/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media`)

Comment: I just tried it and I found the image sent from whatsapp web in above path `media/sent'. if you still can't find it I am surprised and maybe take a backup of Whatsapp, uninstall and re-install cleanly? Also make sure you are on the latest version

Comment: @beeshyams Ok, I have found the folder, and the images. I deleted the .nomedia file, but after sending another image, it appeared again, the images are not in my gallery.

Edit: There is a folder of sent WA-Images in my gallery, but the new images only appear there after deleting the .nomedia file again, but it won't stay deleted

Comment: @beeshyams Media visibility is already on :/

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to automatically download and save sent media from WhatsApp web to mobile, but there's a workaround.

You need two mobile numbers and the ability to run two WhatsApp accounts either using a built-in dual account feature if available or using a third-party dual app provider to achieve this (for a second mobile number, there are several apps like TextNow which gives you an American temporary number for free and you can make WhatsApp accounts with it and even get those numbers permanent for dirt cheap prices)

Once you someway managed two WhatsApp accounts, the rest is rather simple - turn auto download media on the number your phone has and send a pic from the desktop using WhatsApp web from another number.

Comment: Actually, no need for 2 numbers. Just create a WhatsApp group and send the image there.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your main problem is getting pics from a PC to show up in your smartphone gallery, presumably an Android.

To get this job done, there isn't a need to hold on to WhatsApp at all and create 2 accounts (although that's an option - the gallery won't catch the pictures from 2nd clone account easily, especially if it's running in some kind of virtual environment). So here are your options.

- **Wired Xfer** from Phone to PC. Connect the phone to the USB port and it'll ask how you want that connection to behave - charging only, file or player. Choose files (or storage). Navigate to the gallery folder which would be `{internal storage}/DCIM/100Andro` (or `Camera` instead of `100Andro`) and copy if there. It will then def. be in your gallery.
- Wireless Transfer. There are a lot of apps like Airdroid that can do this. (Many times the device manufacturer throws in their homemade tool). Follow these guides [*here*](https://www.alphr.com/computing/1000231/how-to-transfer-files-from-pc-to-android-phone-using-wi-fi-manage-your-media/) & [*here (video guide*)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qoPVeObuWF8) to get Wireless transfer working.
- `adb connect`. Refer to this [XDA guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vr0GLIufzkM)

In either case, for pics to show up in your gallery without hassle, they need to be copied to `{internal storage}/DCIM/100Andro` (or `Camera` instead of `100Andro`). You can use a non-stock powerful 3rd-party gallery app like F-stop that can scan all places on your phone for pictures instead of just a few limited paths.